# pyGObject transparent cursor

Tags: python, gtk3, pygobject

How can I get a transparent cursor using Python GTK3 and pyGObject. I have search the internet high and low but  can not find anthing. I have found a lot of example using pixmap but I believe pyGObject doesn't have pixmap. I can't seem to find any documentation on what replaces pixmap. Help I'm stuck.

Thanks
Sam

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the easiest solution to get a transparent cursor:

```
from gi.repository import Gtk, Gdk

win = Gtk.Window(title="Hello World")
win.show_all()
cursor = Gdk.Cursor.new(Gdk.CursorType.BLANK_CURSOR)
win.get_window().set_cursor(cursor)
Gtk.main()
```

Answer (score 3):

This code will make the cursor invisible instead of transparent.
But I hope you can modify it, to do so:

```
from gi.repository import Gtk, Gdk
import cairo

s = cairo.ImageSurface(cairo.FORMAT_A1, 1, 1)
cursor_pixbuf = Gdk.pixbuf_get_from_surface(s, 0, 0, 1, 1)
cursor = Gdk.Cursor.new_from_pixbuf(Gdk.Display.get_default(), \
                                    cursor_pixbuf, 0, 0)
win = Gtk.Window(title="Hello World")
win.show_all()
win.get_window().set_cursor(cursor)
Gtk.main()
```

Comment: Thank you so much, This works great, I have spent many hours trying to solve this one. :D